# Why does the result of my arithmetical calculation vary with Bash?

Tags: bash

First calculation using bash (( arithmetic expression ))
Second calculation parsing expression through bc

```
$ echo $(( 2232071586215447345536/1000000 ))
15553296591

$ echo 2232071586215447345536/1000000 | bc -l
2232071586215447
```

Why do the resulting values differ?

Comment: Because it overflows.

Comment: Aside :  `bc` gave you the right answer here

Comment: This may be helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117280/what-is-the-rationale-for-the-bash-shell-not-warning-you-of-arithmetic-overflow

Comment: Thanks! I now wish to simulate the overflow in something like python. Would this be possible? 

As i'd like to preserve the overflow/integer length to parse into another process.
ie, 
date/gdate -d @$((2232071586215447345536/1000000))